# Erro ao fazer push origin master no github

Tags: git, github

Estou com o seguinte erro no github quando vou fazer o push.

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Eu criei o repositório e como eu já estava com o projeto criado, fiz:

```
git remote add git@github.com:andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
git config --global user.name "andredsn"
git config --global user.email "andresoteropolitano10@gmail.com"  
git add .  
git commit -m "primeiro commit"
git push origin master
```

Nesta última linha que dar o erro. Provavelmente não es´ta encontrando o repositório.

Como a linha:

```
git remote add git@github.com:andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git >
```

adiciona o remoto via ssh, então apaguei com:

```
git remote rm origim master
```

Digitei: gite remote -v e não tem nenhum repositório, então acho que removi. Mas aparece o erro quando vou adicionar o remoto via https:

```
git remote add https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
```

dar o erro:

```
 C:\projetos\ArquiteturaSoftware>git remote add https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Eu queria um comando para mostrar se estou conectado com o github já que usamos o `git config --global user.name` e `git config --global user.email` para a nossa identificação.

Comment: Você importou sua chave SSH no Github? https://github.com/settings/keys

Comment: Você tentou fazer isso apenas com SSH? Tente com HTTPS.

Comment: @Ricardo Moraleida

Não estou usando ssh e já usei poucas vezes antes apenas pelo terminal. Acho muito trabalhoso o ssh para quem usa o terminal.

Comment: @Ack Lay Estou usando como https mesmo.

Comment: Você está fazendo isso localmente na sua máquina ou algum server?

Comment: @Ack Lay estou fazendo em minha máquina local.

Comment: recomendo usar gitkraken facilitara muito na resolução de erros

Comment: Execute o comando    git remote -v para saber se estou conectado com o github, assim você vai saber seu origin de fetch e push.
Lembre que precisa estar dentro da pasta que contem seu .git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você usou a URL de SSH (`git@github.com...`) para adicionar o remote, por isso ele procura a sua chave.

A URL de HTTPS tem esse formato:

```
https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
```

entao faça:

```
$ git remote add https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
```

e ele vai passar a pedir usuário e senha.

(não se esqueça de remover o remote SSH primeiro)

Answer (score 5):

Se você deseja realizar esse procedimento usando HTTPS, siga os passos abaixo:

1. `$ git init` : Faça isso já dentro do diretório desejado
2. `$ git remote add -f origin https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git`
3. `$ git add .`
4. `$ git commit -m "First commit - send project"`
5. `$ git push origin master`

Veja mais detalhes no artigo sobre [Trabalhando com Remotos](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

**EDIT:** 
O erro que está aparecendo ali após a edição da sua pergunta é que você não está seguindo a sintaxe do GIT corretamente. Veja como deve ser o básico:

```
$ git remote add [<opões>] <nome> <url>
```

No seu caso seria o passo 2 como mencionei acima. Veja:

`$ git remote add -f origin https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git`

Comment: eu apaguei o projeto, criei outro, toda sua sequência em sua resposta funcionou, exceto o quinto passo. Dá o erro: > To https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftw
are.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details. >

Comment: @AndréNascimento qual erro dá?!

Comment: Quando digito: git remote -v mostra:

> origin  https://github.com/andredsn/ArquiteturaSoftware.git (push) >

erre push entre parênteses pode indicar o possível erro?

Comment: não tem esse comando `git remote -v` no quito passo. E (push) não quer indicar nenhum erro. Acho que seu caso já foi resolvido né?! Abs. Boa sorte.

Comment: Quase resolvido. Mas valeu pela ajuda, parte do caminho já foi percorrido.

Answer (score -4):

resolvi desta forma:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/bla.../bla bla ...
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```